# setTimeout()/setInterval() won't execute. **I AM passing the function object - not executing the function

Tags: javascript

The block I'm having issues with is the following:

```
setInterval(checkInput, 5000);
```

where

```
var checkInput = function (letter) {
    console.log("This executed")
    if (ncorrect > 25)
        clearInterval();
    if (document.getElementById('keyinput').value === letter)
        ncorrect++;
    else
        ncorrect = 0;
}
```

I have read the SO posts where the issue is that the function passed looks like `setTimeout(function(), 500)` and the issue is the `()`, but I am clearly not doing that.

When debugging it seems that the function never actually executes at all, and the setTimeout()/setInterval() WILL NOT wait the given amount of time. I get no errors or warnings. Any insight is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: try setInterval('checkInput', 5000);

Answer (score 1):

it all works for me, the only errors I get are:
- `ncorrect` is undefined
- I don't have `document.getElementById('keyinput')` on my page ;)

The rest should be fine. Do you have `ncorrect` and `#keyinput` defined

Comment: Yup! `#keyinput` is `<input id="keyinput" type="text">` and `ncorrect` is right at the beginning `var ncorrect = 0;`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working for me.  I did notice some other bugs in it, though:

The first is that your code won't be able to clear the interval.  You have to pass `clearInterval` an argument like so:

```
var checkInput = function (letter) {
    console.log("This executed")
    if (ncorrect > 25)
        clearInterval(interval);
    if (document.getElementById('keyinput').value === letter)
        ncorrect++;
    else
        ncorrect = 0;
}

var interval = setInterval(checkInput, 5000);
```

The second is that your `checkInput` function takes a parameter of `letter`.  As it stands, you aren't passing anything to the function.  To do so, you would have to do something like:

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    var letter = 'a' //whatever value you want to pass
    checkInput(letter);
}, 5000);
```

Anyway, best of luck to you :)